# Convert an image to 16 bit color depth

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, compact-framework, image-manipulation

I need to take a screen shot and convert that screen shot to a 16 bit color depth.

I am using C# and .net cf 3.5.

I think I could adapt [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836632/convert-image-to-1-bpp-bitmap-in-net-compact-framework/1843590#1843590) to do it, but I want to know if that is overkill.  Is there a way to do this just using .NET CF (ie, no/less p-invokes.)

If it can be done just using .NET CF then it would be easier on maintainers that will have to work on the code at a later date.

Comment: The solution you used is like what I would propose, only I'd binary write PNG instead (or depending on use gzip-compressed BMP might be more suitable but you'd need custom image tools to handle them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you are converting from this shows how to convert a 24bit to 16bit.

[Convert 24-bit bmp to 16-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378690/convert-24-bit-bmp-to-16-bit)

Comment: For future reference, its better etiquette to make links to other SO questions as comments against the original question. That way this question can be closed as a duplicate.