# Compress UIImage reducing color depth

Tags: ios, uiimage, compression

I have a massive 4K x 4K image I need to put in an app, but the memory grows 100MB instantly.
This image is in grayscale, so I wonder if, instead of reducing the resolution I could reduce the color depth and not use some of the channels.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you seen that answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140322/reducing-color-depth-in-an-image-is-not-reducin-the-file-size

Comment: Oh very interesting indeed. I will have a look about implementing this directly on obj-c