# UIImage - change color depth - Quantize

Tags: ios, uiimage

I need to lower the color depth of a UIImage but I cannot figure out how to do it. The result should be the same as applying indexed color in Photoshop.

My target to have a low color depth (32 colors or lower). Perhaps it is my fault but I did no find the way to do it. Surprisingly there is no CoreImage filter for this.

## EDIT

To give you a hint.

### Original picture

[image]

### Desired result

[image]

## EDIT 2

OK I learned that the process is called quantization (or similar :-)). I found very nice source code called [pngnq on sourceforge](http://pngnq.sourceforge.net). While it is nice it is a bit slow specially on older iPhone devices. But it keeps your code small at least.

ImageMagick was the other alternative I found. I edited my answer as I managed to make my code a bit shorter.

```
- (UIImage *) convertImageToIndexed:(UIImage *)image noOfColors:(int)noOfColors withoutTransformation:(BOOL) noTransformation{
UIImage * result;
@autoreleasepool {
    MagickWandGenesis();
    MagickWand * magick_wand = NewMagickWand();
    NSData * dataObject = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    MagickBooleanType status;
    status = MagickReadImageBlob(magick_wand, [dataObject bytes], [dataObject length]);
    if (status == MagickFalse) {
        NSLog(@"OOOOPS");
        return image;
    }

    status = MagickQuantizeImage(magick_wand, noOfColors, MagickGetImageColorspace(magick_wand)  , 0, NO, NO);
    if (status == MagickFalse) {
        NSLog(@"OOOPS");
        return image;
    }

    size_t my_size;
    unsigned char * my_image = MagickGetImageBlob(magick_wand, &my_size);
    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:my_image length:my_size];
    free(my_image);
    magick_wand = DestroyMagickWand(magick_wand);
    MagickWandTerminus();
    UIImage * result = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10140972/3993103

Comment: Have you looked into vImage and or CoreGraphics at all?

Comment: Also your looking for 3-bit format right?

Comment: @Roecrew: vImage no (as I have no idea what it is... yet), CoreGraphics yes. I believe I am not looking for a 3-bit format. I am looking for indexed format like a GIF file (which is not 3-bit as far as I know but I can be wrong). Pixel colors should come from a look-up-table which needs to be generated. But I have no idea how to create such LUT and/or convert the image to meet that LUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using imagemagick wand library. It was not obvious how to use imagemagick neither. I do not know if there is a better way to code this as I am nor a coding hero neither an imagemagick expert.

Here is the code I used:

```
- (UIImage *) convertImageToIndexed:(UIImage *)image noOfColors:(int)noOfColors withoutTransformation:(BOOL) noTransformation {
    UIImage * result;
    @autoreleasepool {
        MagickWandGenesis();
        MagickWand * magick_wand = NewMagickWand();
        NSData * dataObject = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        MagickBooleanType status;
        status = MagickReadImageBlob(magick_wand, [dataObject bytes], [dataObject length]);
        if (status == MagickFalse) {
            NSLog(@"OOOOPS");
            return image;
        }

        status = MagickQuantizeImage(magick_wand, noOfColors, MagickGetImageColorspace(magick_wand)  , 0, NO, NO);
        if (status == MagickFalse) {
            NSLog(@"OOOPS");
            return image;
        }

        size_t my_size;
        unsigned char * my_image = MagickGetImageBlob(magick_wand, &my_size);
        NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:my_image length:my_size];
        free(my_image);
        magick_wand = DestroyMagickWand(magick_wand);
        MagickWandTerminus();
        UIImage * result = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        return result;
    }
}
```