# Use Bitmap.ConvertFormat in C# (PixelFormat from 24 bits to 16 bits RGB555 with dithering)

Tags: c#, bitmap, pixelformat

Any easy way? I am trying to convert the PixelFormat from 24 bits image to 16 bits RGB555 with dithering (for a portable device). I tested already a lot of approaches:

- AForge.NET
- FreeImage
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66341/A-Simple-Yet-Quite-Powerful-Palette-Quantizer-in-C

They all work poorly. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536306(v=vs.85).aspx

I found a GDI+ wrapper, but this function is missing.

Thanks!

Comment: In a first attempt, I'd do a stupid RGB888 to RGB555 color conversion and see what it looks like. RGB555 is probably still good enough so you don't even need dithering.

Comment: [`RGB555`](http://www.imagingcontrol.com/en_US/support/documentation/class/PixelformatRGB555.htm) doesn't looks complicated. Have you tried a simple math, like `uint16 rgb555color = ((r / x) << 10) | ((g / x) << 5) | (b / x)`, where `x` is 256 / 32 (not sure about 24 bit format, if it's a byte per color component, then 256, otherwise - replace 256 with that).

Comment: I am trying to build an alternative toolkit for the HP Prime calculator, everything works but this image conversion :/ https://github.com/eried/PrimeComm/ in the PC looks OK but gradients images look aweful in the device itself, so I really need a smart dithering (Photoshop RGB555 dithering looks perfect). In AForge I can do some dithering, in fact I already implemented them all http://cl.ly/THlP the problem is the color table is in 24 bits (AForge does not work with RGB555 for dithering), so after the conversion it always looks bad (even with a palette 'artificially' limited to RGB555 values)

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the image by using Bitmap class in the constructor pass the parameters for the conversion format and it will render the image with the PixelFormat you have mentioned.

### Some code:

```
    public static Bitmap ConvertTo16bpp(Image img) {
    //you can also use Image.FromFile(fileName);//fileName can be absolute path of the image.
    var bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height,System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);
    using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    gr.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height));
    return bmp;
   }
```

### Suggestions

If you have some simple requirements you would not probably need AForge.NET (An excellent library for image processing) and you may go with a simple solution,but that's your decision to make.

### Links

- [system.drawing.imaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Convert-24-bit-bmp-to-16-bit *(Solution Adpated from)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378690/convert-24-bit-bmp-to-16-bit)

Comment: The above implementation is effectively the same that is being used also in *AForge.NET's* [Image.Clone](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/692eb465-79b9-1027-339b-fe8979a7a9c4.htm) method for changing pixel format.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson Thank you for mentioning this.

Comment: The problem with this, without dithering is the massive "banding" effect that appears. I am using that method already, in fact I am just locking the bits under that format: https://github.com/eried/PrimeComm/blob/master/PrimeLib/Utilities.cs#L79 the thing is the ConvertFormat in GDI+ includes a lot of Dithering methods :/