# Is there a way to convert 16-bit color to 24-bit color efficiently while avoiding floating-point math?

Tags: c#, performance, colors, bitmap, bit-manipulation

I'm decoding a .BMP file, and I'm at a point where I need to handle 16-bit colors. The entire codebase uses 32-bit colors (R, G, B, A), so I need to convert the color to a 24-bit RGB value (one byte for each color).

Each component of the color is 5-bit as per the specification (1 bit is wasted). My code is as follows:

```cs
ushort color = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 54 + i);
byte blue  = (byte)((color | 0b0_00000_00000_11111) / 31f * 255);
byte green = (byte)(((color | 0b0_00000_11111_00000) >> 5) / 31f * 255);
byte red   = (byte)(((color | 0b0_11111_00000_00000) >> 10) / 31f * 255);
```

However, this doesn't seem particularly efficient. I tried doing `color << (8 - 5)`, which makes the process much faster and avoids floating-point conversions, but it isn't accurate - a value of 31 (11111) converts to 248. Is there a way to achieve this with some other bit-manipulation hack, or am I forced to convert each number to a float just to change the color space?

Comment: Can you just [draw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2379838/11683) to a `Graphics` created off a `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb` target bitmap?

Comment: I'm in an environment which doesn't have access to the `Graphics` class (the Cosmos framework, https://github.com/cosmosos/cosmos), so I need to implement all rendering methods, color handling code, etc. myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only the floating point conversions can be avoided but also multiplications and divisions. From my [implementation](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing/blob/master/KGySoft.Drawing.Core/Drawing/Imaging/_Structs/Color16Rgb555.cs):

```
internal struct Color16Rgb555
{
    private const ushort redMask = 0b01111100_00000000;
    private const ushort greenMask = 0b00000011_11100000;
    private const ushort blueMask = 0b00011111;

    private ushort _value;

    internal Color16Rgb555(ushort value) => _value = value;

    internal byte R => (byte)(((_value & redMask) >> 7) | ((_value & redMask) >> 12));
    internal byte G => (byte)(((_value & greenMask) >> 2) | ((_value & greenMask) >> 7));
    internal byte B => (byte)(((_value & blueMask) << 3) | ((_value & blueMask) >> 2));
}
```

Usage:

```
var color = new Color16Rgb555(BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 54 + i));
byte blue  = color.B;
byte green = color.G;
byte red   = color.R;
```

It produces 255 for 31 because it fills up the remaining 3 bits with the 3 MSB bits of the actual 5 bit value.

But assuming your `data` is a byte array you have an even more convenient option if you use my [drawing libraries](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing):

```cs
// to interpret your data array as 16BPP pixels with RGB555 format:
var my16bppBitmap = BitmapDataFactory.CreateBitmapData(
    data, // your back buffer
    new Size(pixelWidth, pixelHeight), // size in pixels
    stride, // the size of one row in bytes
    KnownPixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);

// now you can get/set pixels normally    
Color somePixel = my16bppBitmap.GetPixel(0, 0);

// For better performance obtain a row first.
var row = my16bppBitmap[0]; // or FirstRow (+MoveNextRow if you wish)
Color32 asColor32 = row[0]; // accessing pixels regardless of PixelFormat
ushort asUInt16 = row.ReadRaw<ushort>(0); // if you know that it's a 16bpp format
```